# spinner list in xamarin using multiple checkbox

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

hello to every one i am working on android using xamarin studio .i am working on spinner list using multiple checkbox selection option my problem is that multiple check box not checked how is missing on my code it works perfectly on single check box

```
private void CreateSpinner()
{

    var spinner = CurrentView.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
    var lst = Util.getitemlist(this.Activity);
    var dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem>(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, lst);
    dataAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemMultipleChoice);
    spinner.Adapter = dataAdapter;

    spinner.ItemSelected += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e) => {

            };

}
```